# Putting 100 words per line

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop

I have a problem were I go through a paragraph of words which is around 1000 words etc and its suppose to puts words divided by space with a max 100 character line length. The row length should be as close as possible but not exceeding the 100 character limit per row.

The problem is I'm simply splitting the string (ignoring the words) every 100 characters. Since I'm rounding this means that some characters might be left over at the last iteration.

I was wondering if anyone can help me fix this problem and create a better function to do this

My JS:

```
const paragraph = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Nam nibh. Nunc varius facilisis eros. Sed erat. In in velit quis arcu ornare laoreet. Curabitur adipiscing luctus massa. Integer ut purus ac augue commodo commodo. Nunc nec mi eu justo tempor consectetuer. Etiam vitae nisl. In dignissim lacus ut ante. Cras elit lectus, bibendum a, adipiscing vitae, commodo et, dui. Ut tincidunt tortor. Donec nonummy, enim in lacinia pulvinar, velit tellus scelerisque augue, ac posuere libero urna eget neque. Cras ipsum. Vestibulum pretium, lectus nec venenatis volutpat, purus lectus ultrices risus, a condimentum risus mi et quam. Pellentesque auctor fringilla neque. Duis eu massa ut lorem iaculis vestibulum. Maecenas facilisis elit sed justo. Quisque volutpat malesuada velit.",

  lines = Math.round(paragraph.length / 100);

let line = 0;

for (let i = 0; lines > i; i++) {
    document.body.innerHTML += paragraph.slice(line, line + 100) + '<br>';
```

Fiddle link:[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/8gs78vra/9/)

The way I figured it, is that we have N which is >=1000 I need to be able to create rows of words separated by spaces where row length >= 100

javascript ain't my strongest point but I gave it a go , so any help on fixing this would be great.

Comment: *Never* use operators like `+=` on `.innerHTML` - it causes the entire element to get serialised from DOM to a string, modified, then converted back to DOM.    Accumulate the HTML in a separate variable, and only after it's all done store it in the DOM.

Comment: @RonTheOld Is requirement 100 words per line or 100 characters per line?

Comment: @guest271314 words :0 so i think urs worked perfectly i just tested it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should split on spaces as long as lines do not exceed 100 characters.
[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/doam8j9t/)

```
var paragraph = 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Nam nibh. Nunc varius facilisis eros. Sed erat. In in velit quis arcu ornare laoreet. Curabitur adipiscing luctus massa. Integer ut purus ac augue commodo commodo. Nunc nec mi eu justo tempor consectetuer. Etiam vitae nisl. In dignissim lacus ut ante. Cras elit lectus, bibendum a, adipiscing vitae, commodo et, dui. Ut tincidunt tortor. Donec nonummy, enim in lacinia pulvinar, velit tellus scelerisque augue, ac posuere libero urna eget neque. Cras ipsum. Vestibulum pretium, lectus nec venenatis volutpat, purus lectus ultrices risus, a condimentum risus mi et quam. Pellentesque auctor fringilla neque. Duis eu massa ut lorem iaculis vestibulum. Maecenas facilisis elit sed justo. Quisque volutpat malesuada velit.';

var result = '';
// While there's text left to parse
while(paragraph.length > 100){
    // Find the last space character in the first 100 characters
  var lastSpace = paragraph.substring(0,100).lastIndexOf(' ');

  // Add the chunk to the results
  result += paragraph.substring(0,lastSpace) + '<br/><br/>';

  // Remove the used chunk from the original body
  paragraph = paragraph.substring(lastSpace + 1);
}

// Add on the last trailing bit
result += paragraph;

document.body.innerHTML = result;
```

Comment: Wouldnt `lastSpace + 1` instead of `.trim()` do it?

Comment: this is a nice answer :)

Comment: This actually was really good and i understood it a bit better :)

Comment: My fault for making the question seem dumb with my English but this is what i wanted

Comment: Haha thanks, I understood your question on the first read so your English is fine!

Answer (score 2):

Your paragraph is of aprox 1000 words, you're not guaranteed to have a multiple of 100 characters and as such the last line might end with slightly less.

You probably want to split the paragraph by each word first, we assume no fancy formatting and just separate by each space in this case.

```
var listWords = paragraph.split(" ");
```

Now you want each line to be at most 100 characters, just iterate over the words and add them to a line till the length of the words is too long

```
var line = "";
var lineLength = 0;
var fullBody = "";
for (var i = 0; i < listWords.length; i++){
   if (lineLength + listWords[i].length > 100){
     fullBody += line + "<br>";
     line = "";
     lineLength = 0;
   }
   line += listWords[i] + " ";
   lineLength += listWords[i].length + 1;
}
document.body.innerHTML += fullBody;
```

This is a fast solution and im sure it can be made better (not leaving trailing spaces), but it should illustrate the way to solve the problem.

as per Jonas w suggestion, let's move innerHTML to the bottom to speed it up.

Comment: *innerHTML* is not just a property but rather a setter. Building a string first and setting the innerHTML once will speed it up...

Comment: Sorry i wrote that twice i fixed it mys elf thank u for this

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.slice()` and increment the parameters passed to the method by `100`

```
let chunks = paragraph.split(/\s/);

for (let i = 0, n = 100; i < chunks.length; i += 100, n += 100) {
  document.body.innerHTML += chunks.slice(i, n).join(" ") + '<br>';
}
```

jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/8gs78vra/18/

To get get 100 characters per line you can use `.match()`, `.lastIndexOf()` and `.slice()`

```js
const paragraph = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Nam nibh. Nunc varius facilisis eros. Sed erat. In in velit quis arcu ornare laoreet. Curabitur adipiscing luctus massa. Integer ut purus ac augue commodo commodo. Nunc nec mi eu justo tempor consectetuer. Etiam vitae nisl. In dignissim lacus ut ante. Cras elit lectus, bibendum a, adipiscing vitae, commodo et, dui. Ut tincidunt tortor. Donec nonummy, enim in lacinia pulvinar, velit tellus scelerisque augue, ac posuere libero urna eget neque. Cras ipsum. Vestibulum pretium, lectus nec venenatis volutpat, purus lectus ultrices risus, a condimentum risus mi et quam. Pellentesque auctor fringilla neque. Duis eu massa ut lorem iaculis vestibulum. Maecenas facilisis elit sed justo. Quisque volutpat malesuada velit.";

let matches = paragraph.match(/.{100}|.+$/g);

let len = [];
      
for (let i = 0; i < matches.length; i++) {
  let str;
  if (matches[i][matches[i].length - 1] === " ") {
    str = matches[i].trim();
  } else {
    let index = matches[i].lastIndexOf(" ");
    str = matches[i].slice(0, index).trim();
    if (matches[i + 1]) {
      matches[i + 1] = matches[i].slice(index) + matches[i + 1];
    }  else {
      str = matches[i].slice(index + 1).trim();
    }
  }
  len.push(str.length);
  document.body.innerHTML += str + "<br>"
}

document.body.innerHTML += "<br>string .length of each line " + len;
```

```css
body {
  white-space:pre;
}
```

Comment: Sorry on phone , could u make a quick fiddle just so i can see, but i think i understand the answer

Comment: Although i have never used the .slice() function yet

Comment: Thank you for this and the fiddle, i will have a look at it later and try and fully understand it, really big help

Comment: @Jonasw Either pattern should render same result

Comment: This doesn't work.   It accumulates 100 *words* at a time, not 100 chars.

Comment: @Alnitak _"This doesn't work. It accumulates 100 words at a time, not 100 chars"_ ? That is the requirement of Question

Comment: @guest271314 no it isn't - read again - the question title is wrong, but the text of the question is clear

Comment: Sorry guys i meant 100 characters per line

Comment: The way i have written it down and gone through it is : Given N words where N >= 1000
Create rows of words separated by spaces where row length >= 100

Comment: @Alnitak See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46718935/putting-100-words-per-line/46719097#comment80385275_46718935. Interpreted gist of requirement. Though can include character delimiter approach at Answer as well